Can't change monitor resolution on Ubuntu on a HP Elitedesk 600 SFF
I have tried several methods from Ask Ubuntu, but I don't seem to be able to get the monitor to work. I tried switching from Wayland to Xorg and here's what happened (see pic). I have tried reinstalling the driver and adding the resolution to XWAYLAND0 and neither worked. I am also using Secure Boot if that makes any difference.
My monitor info:
:~$ lshw -c video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1024,768
       resources: irq:125 memory:b0000000-b0ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

XWAYLAND0 error:

